# Is the drug used to stop infection in The Rock real?

Tags: realism, the-rock

In The Rock (1996), Nicolas Cage used an injection to stop himself from being infected by the deadly virus. Is that a real drug in real life or just some fictional creation? How does it stop virus infection in the movie?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There is no 'deadly virus' in The Rock.  The weapon that is stolen by Frank Hummel's team is [VX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VX_(nerve_agent)), a so-called nerve agent, a chemical that (amongst other things) interferes with your muscles and causes you to asphyxiate through a lack of ability to breathe.

The antidote that they use in the movie is [Atropine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropine) which is a real chemical used to counteract the effects of nerve agents such as VX.

The effects of VX are not entirely realistically shown in the movie, but the agent itself and the antidote Atropine are real-life and not a fictional creation.

Comment: Hey thank you very much! I was wondering if I should ask in Medical or Biology exchanges, but I guess we also have experts in Movie exchange!

Comment: @user1589188 On those SE sites it would be more appropriate to ask about specific chemical and neurological action mechanisms of the chemicals or their effects. I wouldn't suggest asking about "how close to reality" something in a movie is on either of them.

Comment: Note that Atropine itself is a pretty nasty poison. The reason you're supposed to use it in cases like that is because the outcome of VX is /worse/, but even if you survive you'll never be well again.

Comment: Indeed @Shadur .... looking it up, its LD50 is less than 500mg.  I guess this is one of the reasons why Goodspeed refuses a preventative Atropine injection in one of the opening scenes.

Comment: @shadur uh, no. From the link in the answer, atropine "is on the World Health Organization's List of Essential Medicines, the safest and most effective medicines needed in a health system." And a LD50 of 453mg isn't very low, especially for something most people can't even get. That would be over 40g in one dose for the average US man, 34g for women.

Comment: @Dallium That LD50 is for oral ingestion. Atropine injection risks appear to be much higher. However, [this reference](https://www.drugs.com/dosage/atropine.html#Usual_Adult_Dose_for_Nerve_Agent_Poisoning) says the typical dosage 0.8-2mg, or 6mg in extreme cases. [Potential side effects](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/atropine-side-effects.html) like dilated pupils, blurred vision, bright light causing pain, nausea, loss of balance, and heart palpitations are more likely to be a reason to refuse a preventative dose. I haven't seen the movie, so I'm partly guessing about that character's motivation.

Comment: Fun fact: The VX delivery system based on "glass balls" used in the movie is entirely made up by Hollyweird, but was later used by "Iraqi informants" when they claimed that Saddam "had nerve gas in storage". Sold to the public!

Comment: if memory serves, Atropine is so nasty, you get a second injection to counteract its side effects

Comment: @iandotkelly: IRL when administering Atropine do you have to stab yourself in the heart with a giant syringe? :)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, link?

Comment: @PaulDraper I had to rack my brain. It's in [HyperNormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperNormalisation), a film by Adam Curtis miraculously and improbably emitted by the BBC. See here: https://youtu.be/fh2cDKyFdyU?t=6314 There must be another source, too.

Comment: A side question, if those ball are a chemical nerve agent why is Nicholas Cages's character so concerned when one of those balls is about to roll off the edge into the ocean and he jumps to grab it just in time. How much damage to marine life could a single ball of nerve gas do?

Comment: It should be noted that actual treatment for nerve agent exposure also includes an injection of diazepam to stop the muscle spasms